# Flag count is incrementing only after page reload

Tags: 8, flags

I have a views with like and unlike flag. When I click on like flag the count not increments. But when I reload the page, then only like's count will change. How can I solve this issue?

**Note**: I have already enabled ajax for my views.

Comment: The count going up on reload sounds like that is the views count incrementing from the statistics module. When you say Flag, are you referring to a specific module? A custom form?

Comment: Yes..Am using flag module in drupal8.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have ajax enabled?

Comment: yes..I have enabled in my view.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and find how to solve it. The [Views Flag Refresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_flag_refresh) module is only available for Drupal 7, but someone ported it to work on Drupal 8, [here is the download link](https://bitbucket.org/Walking_Dexter/views_flag_refresh/downloads/).

I find it in [this issue comment by WalkingDexter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_flag_refresh/issues/2929394#comment-12642874).

In my case I need it to work on Drupal 9, so it is necessary to change a line in a file in the downloaded custom module [as Akash_Daimari explains in this comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_flag_refresh/issues/2929394#comment-13688369).

The module would go in /modules/custom/

In the view you have to use Ajax and add the flag in 'Flag refresh' options.

As a note, in the View preview the count does not update, but on the page it does.